# Monotonic curvature and self intersections.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, curves

I'm trying to prove that if $\alpha: I \to \Bbb R^2$ is a differentiable curve, where $I$ is an interval, has strictly monotonic curvature, then $\alpha$ has no self-intersections.

**My attempt**: We suppose WLOG that $\alpha$ is parametrized by arc-length. If the curvature $\kappa$ is strictly monotonic, and is defined on an interval, then $\kappa$ is injective. We consider $t_0, t_1 \in I$ such that $\alpha(t_0) = \alpha(t_1)$, and I want to prove that $t_0 = t_1$. If I manage to get $\kappa(t_0) = \kappa(t_1)$, then I'm done. For me, it is rather clear that this will be indeed the case, but I'm failing to justify that. My first thought was that: $$\alpha(t_0) = \alpha(t_1) \implies \alpha'(t_0) = \alpha'(t_1) \implies \alpha''(t_0) = \alpha''(t_1) \implies \kappa(t_0) = \kappa(t_1)$$
and so we would use $\kappa$'s injectivity to get $t_0 = t_1$. But the first two implications are clearly false, in general. Is there some way to use the hypothesis we have to conclude these implications, or is there another approach to the problem whatsoever? Thanks for your time.

---

On the other hand, I think that this might be false, since we could "glue" some curves together, like this:

[image]

What to do?

---

**Edit:** As pointed by Semiclassical in the comments, the image on the pic is *not* a counter-example, since the curvature first increases, then decreases. But the fault in my first attempt still remains.

Comment: Can you clarify the objection you're seeing in that screenshot?

Comment: This would be a counter-example in the case that the curvature is constant, no? But it seems to me that we could build a similiar thing with the curvature being non-constant, varying just a little bit.

Comment: Partly I was just having a hard time reading it. But I don't see how that's an example with constant curvature: indeed, the curvature is discontinuous at the two points of gluing and is much higher at the turn.

Comment: Well, you're right.. there no hypothesis of the curvature being constant. But even if we added that, the fault in my argument right before the pic will still be there..

Comment: I was misreading you. I see your point, yes: there's no reason to expect that the curvature and tangent vector at a self-intersection  are identical.

Comment: FYI: For a smooth version of your example above, a [prolate cycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateCycloid.html) does nicely.

Comment: The intuitive reason for absence of self intersection: Take any point $p$ on the curve. Draw the circle tangent to the curve at  $p$ and having the same radius as the curvature radius at $p$. Then one part of the curve is strictly inside the circle, while the other is strictly outside, so they do not intersect each other.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/671293/137524) looks to give the necessary ingredients to make that rigorous.

Comment: Nice question, this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a corollary of the [Kneser’s Nesting Theorem](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes5U.pdf). Any self-intersection will give two osculating circles with at least one intersection, contradicting this theorem.